# Is there any advantage to leveling more than one character of the same class in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've noticed in the achievements that there's one for each class for leveling 2 Heros of that class to 60. Is there any advantage to doing this is or is it simply for the achievement's sake?

Comment: Is "fun" not an advantage?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot God forbid I leave a quality as nebulous and subjective as "fun" out of my question. Kindly take your crap elsewhere.

Comment: I can't tell if you are joking T_T

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I wasn't, but if your post wasn't as antagonistic as I initially thought then we can chalk this up to a simple misunderstanding of intent, I suppose.

Comment: It should be noted that I am **not** the one who downvoted, but I can see how it would seem that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the advent of the new skills system that allows such easy respeccing, the only strict advantages are purely cosmetic ones:

1. you can then have max levels of both male and female character models, and
2. you get the achievement.

Other than that, any other differences would all be self set, i.e. attempting to level by only shooting Magic Missile at the darkness, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Another advantage is that it's also a way to experience normal and hardcore mode with the same class

Comment: Ah, yes. i didn't think about that. Gonna have a hell of a time getting to level 60 on hardcore, though :)